# How Can I Integrate Rails with Inertia.js and Using Vue.js as The Front-end?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, vuejs3, inertiajs

I've done this in Django and Laravel (the most easier) but can I do this in Rails?

I've installed vite_rails gem and inertia_rails gem but due to lack of documentation, I'm just stuck when integrating those two. I'm not quite familiar with Rails commands.